# Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, AspNet.Identity.MongoDB and mongocsharpdriver

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api, claims-based-identity

+after successfully implementing **Token Based Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity**, i wished to change my implementation to use MongoDB instead of MSSQL with Entity Framework, with the help of this [**application here**](https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication)....truth be said, i dont fully understand how this should be done, but at least i know what i want my application to behave. i want to follow this [***IMPLEMENTATION HERE***](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2011/10/02/a-mongodb-tutorial-using-c-and-asp-net-mvc/), using *AspNet.Identity.MongoDB* **and** *mongocsharpdriver*...and so far, here,s what I've done:
**Account Controller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Http;
using withMongoDB.HelperClasses.Services;
using withMongoDB.Models.Account;

namespace withMongoDB.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/Account")]
    public class AccountsController : ApiController
    {
        AccountsService _accountsService = new AccountsService();

        // POST api/Account/Register
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [Route("Register")]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            await _accountsService.Register(userModel);

            return Ok();
        }

        private IHttpActionResult GetErrorResult(IdentityResult result)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                return InternalServerError();
            }

            if (!result.Succeeded)
            {
                if (result.Errors != null)
                {
                    foreach (string error in result.Errors)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("", error);
                    }
                }

                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    // No ModelState errors are available to send, so just return an empty BadRequest.
                    return BadRequest();
                }

                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

then the register method from the controller should be taken by the **accounts Service**

```
using AspNet.Identity.MongoDB;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using withMongoDB.Models.Account;

namespace withMongoDB.HelperClasses.Services
{
    public class AccountsService 
    {
        private readonly MongoAccountsConnectionHelper<UserProfile> _accounts;

        public AccountsService()
        {
            _accounts = new MongoAccountsConnectionHelper<UserProfile>();
        }

        public async Task<IdentityResult> Register(UserModel userModel)
        {
            var userprofile = new UserProfile
            {
                UserName = userModel.UserName
            };

            var result = await _accounts.CreateAsync(userprofile, userModel.Password);

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

and finally the **MongoAccountsConnectionHelper** takes the result of the accounts service class to mongo database....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace withMongoDB.HelperClasses 
{
    using AspNet.Identity.MongoDB;
    //using Entities;
    using MongoDB.Bson;
    using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Conventions;
    using MongoDB.Driver;
    using System.Configuration;
    using withMongoDB.Models.Account;
    public class MongoAccountsConnectionHelper
    {
        private readonly MongoCollection<UserProfile> userProfileCollection;
        public MongoDatabase Database { get; private set; }
        public MongoAccountsConnectionHelper()
        {
            var pack = new ConventionPack()
            {
                new CamelCaseElementNameConvention(),
                new EnumRepresentationConvention(BsonType.String)
            };

            ConventionRegistry.Register("CamelCaseConvensions", pack, t => true);

            var mongoUrlBuilder = new MongoConnectionStringBuilder(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoDB"].ConnectionString);
            Database = new MongoClient().GetServer().GetDatabase(mongoUrlBuilder.DatabaseName);

            userProfileCollection = Database.GetCollection<UserProfile>("users");
        }

        public MongoCollection<UserProfile> Users
        {
            get { return userProfileCollection; }
        }
    }
}
```

any help, tips, ideas, or opinions will be highly appreciated....{**should i consider alternatives like MembershipReboot and IdentityReboot by brockallen?**}

Answer (score 0):

To do it smoothly, you need first to remove the dependency on "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework", by providing your own user class/table (which should implements IUser as a minimum), and Also you need to implement the UserManager class (which should imeplements UserManager, and finally you need to implement the UserStore class (which should implement IUserStore as minimum) where T is the Id type in the User Table.

Once you done the above, then it is the UserStore where you can change to use MongoDB.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +thanks Omar for your response. i managed to do it but exactly as it was in the sample project {https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication}, including the use of autofac...i posted another question about how to remove autofac {http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829498/remove-autofac-from-owin-start-up-class}, i was hoping you can help...i will use autofac later once i learn it

Comment: @McKabue -I am also referring to the same sample project but I am not able to find the IdentityContext file.Could you please share the location